# Getting the duration of an MP3 file with JavaScript using "Web Audio API" and "AudioContext"

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api, audiocontext

Is there any way to get the duration of an `MP3` file with `JavaScript` using `Web Audio API` and `AudioContext`?

I can get that duration with the `HTML5` element: `<audio/>` but I want to use the `Web Audio API`.

Below is the code I have so far. If you have any suggestion, please, fork my code on: `CodePen.io` and post the link.

`CodePen.io` code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QZwyqd

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 const URL = 'https://www.tophtml.com/snl/15.mp3';
 let url = URL + '?nocache='+(new Date()).getTime();
 let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
 audio.setAttribute('src', url);
 audio.addEventListener('durationchange', function() {
  log('way 1: ' + this.duration);
 });
 getAudioDurationWithAudioContext().then((duration) => {
  log('way 2: ' + duration);
 });
 log('...');
});
function getAudioDurationWithAudioContext() {
 // PLEASE, IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION AND "FORK" THIS CODE
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
   resolve('???.???');
  }, 1000);
 });
}
function log(text, append = true) {
 let logger = document.querySelector('.logger');
 if (text == '') {
  logger.innerHTML = '';
  return;
 }
 if (!append)
  logger.innerHTML = '';
 let entry = document.createElement('div');
 entry.innerHTML = text;
 logger.appendChild(entry);
}
```

```css
.logger {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: monospace;
 white-space: pre;
 font-size: 13px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 background-color: #d4e4ff;
}
.logger {
 padding: 4px; 
}
.divider {
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <audio controls preload="auto"></audio>
</div>

<div class="logger"></div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible to use `AudioContext` without audio tag. so even if it's possible to get the duration using `AudioContext` you will still end up using the audio tag

Answer (score 2):

Once you've got your [AudioBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) it has a duration property. This is a double representing the duration in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to do this and without an audio tag. You need to download audio file using Ajax/XMLHttpRequest and decode the file like this:

```
// Step 1: We need AudioContext instance to decode audio files.
var context = new AudioContext();


// Step 2: Download a .mp3 file using AJAX
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener('load', fileLoaded);
request.open('GET', 'https://www.tophtml.com/snl/15.mp3');
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.send();


// Step 3: File downloaded, need to be decoded now.
function fileLoaded() {
    if (request.status < 400)
        context.decodeAudioData(request.response, fileDecoded);
}


// Step 4: File decoded, we can get the duration.
function fileDecoded(audioBuffer) {

    // This is the duration you want, in seconds:
    audioBuffer.duration;

}
```

Comment: You can also do this from a file that's loaded into a input field (`type="file"`).